# Preprocessor error in NSLog

Tags: objective-c, iphone, c-preprocessor

In `BlaBlaBla_prefix.pch` I define the following:

```
#import "SMDeviceManager.h"
#define DeviceSpecificResourceName(name) [SMDeviceManager deviceSpecificResourceName:(name)];
```

But if I know use this function in my code inside a NSog()-call, I get the following error during compilation:

> Expected ")" before ";" token.

But if I  save the output in a variable ,instead of directly calling the function in NSLog, it works.

```
NSString *test = DeviceSpecificResourceName(@"eintest.png");
NSLog(@"%@", test);
```

This logs the expected value. B But in the other way it fails at compiling. What am I doing wrong? Can you please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define DeviceSpecificResourceName(name) [SMDeviceManager deviceSpecificResourceName:(name)];
//                                                                                          ^ remove
```

Remove the final semicolon.

---

If you keep the `;`, the statement `NSLog(@"%@", DeviceSpecificResourceName(@"eintest.png"))` will be replaced as

```
NSLog(@"%@", [SMDeviceManager deviceSpecificResourceName:(@"eintest.png")];);
//                                                                        ^
```

which of course is a syntax error.

Comment: How stupid of me! That's it. Thank you very much. It's not the first time I made this error. But this time I didn't look for the error in the #define part... Thank you for your answer!